# Is -std=c++11 appropriate for production code using gcc 4.8.1

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

The gcc website still says: "GCC's support for C++11 is still experimental." (http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).
I feel hesitant arguing within my organization to press for a move to C++11 features while the people releasing the compiler say this.
Should I argue for "-std=c++11" if gcc says it is experimental?

Comment: I don't think there would really be a problem from all the use of it I've seen. It's very standard-conforming, and bugs don't come up too often.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html looks quite good

Comment: Consider your unit test coverage when asking yourself this question. :)

Comment: @chris: bugs as in "doesn't compile" or bugs as in "doesn't do the right thing"? :) I can live with the former one.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, I've seen both, though the former is more common, it seems, or a third category of it compiling code that shouldn't compile. These really aren't discovered on here that frequently.

Comment: Not only the support is still experimental, it is also incomplete. You could argue for using a specific C++11 feature if you can demonstrate a strong benefit for this particular application.

Comment: if 
FB can use C++11 with g++ I think you can too.  :D

Comment: (opinion) If you're on windows, then the answer is "NO". Last week I spent two days trying to build qt4 using mingw with gcc 4.7.1. I hit linker bug - while compiling QtGUId dll ld.exe has been constantly running out of memory and crashing. Apparently it needs more than 2 gigabytes of RAM to link a dll. As a result I came to conclusion that mingw port of gcc (or gcc itself) is quite buggy and should probably be avoided for quite a while. I don't want to be fighting bugs introduced by thrd-party tools instead of working on my own project.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is one of those things that you can argue until something rare happens (cows coming home, hell freezing, etc) and not find a resolution.

The key here is that "experimental support" probably means that if you are on a support contract for GCC, you probably can't raise a "defect" ticket against the 11 features. But on the other hand, we can probably expect most features to be fairly robust, as they have been discussed for a LONG time before C++11 specification came out.

The key to determine if YOUR product is correctly built by the compiler will still rely on YOUR testing of the product code (both as units at various levels (functions, classes, shared libraries, exectutables as makes sense for your product) and "complete" product). This doesn't really change based on whether the C++11 support is experimental or not. Even non-experimental code breaks at times in compilers.

The other part to look at is of course "what benefit do we get, and how much risk does it influence to the project". Are you changing the ENTIRE system, or just a small part in one corner, that if it breaks could be worked around by doing some more steps in a different way?

In the end, it's really something where you have to go with "what's the best balance between moving forward and avoiding risk".

Comment: I tend to agree. I wonder what the org means when they say "experimental." Clang, et. al., doesn't say that. I really think we have a case for it, but gcc's statement seems to defeat my case.

Comment: Obviously, I can't answer for "what GCC means by experimental" directly - it is generally used as a "we haven't tested this fully yet" (or "it hasn't passed the validation tests" or something else along those lines - which may be because the validation hasn't been done, or there are blooming great holes in the support - I don't think it's the latter, but it may well be the former). And of course, it's a little bit dependant on what your organisation does and how well you test things, etc. I'm not sure I'd use an "experimental" compiler for nuclear power stations, say. Game development, sure

Comment: @John In my journey with g++ 4.8.1 I have found that, for example, one possible reason for them to label this as "experimental" can be the fact that the threading model in that particular C++11 implementation is borrowed from the POSIX threading library, so it's not really implemented by the compiler or by the standard library (libstdc++), it's a third part library basically and the GNU has no control over this project.